# SQLSRV Not working

Tags: date, drop-down-menu, format, sqlsrv

I am trying to populate dropdown list from SQL Query that is in DATE format through SQLSRV function but it is not working. Please help.

```
<?php

$serverName1 = "kk12334";
$connectionInfo1 = array( "Database"=>"Fruits");
$conn1 = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName1, $connectionInfo1);
$sql1="SELECT [ArrivalDate] as ADate, [ArrivalCompany] as ACompany from Fruits";
$stmt1 = sqlsrv_query( $conn1, $sql1 );

while ($data=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))

{ 

$checkdate= $data[ADate];
$checkacct=$data[ACompany];

$checkdateDisplay = $checkdate . "-" . $checkacct;
$checkdateDisplay = substr($checkdate, 5, 2) . "-" . substr($checkdate, 8, 2) . "-" .  substr($checkdate, 0, 4) . "_:_" . $checkacct;
echo "<option value='$checkdateDisplay'>$checkdateDisplay</option>\n";

}

?>
```

Comment: Please remove the following code. it is repetitive. $checkdateDisplay = $checkdate . "-" . $checkacct; Still it is not working. Please help.

Comment: Please note this issue is caused only when I include date format column from SQL Server. Is there a separate syntax for DATE?

Answer (score 1):

your connection array does not follow the correct syntax and leaves out important information:

```
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>$myDB, "PWD"=>$myPass, "UID"=>$myUser);
```

this mistake prevents the code from connecting to your database.  You must supply both a username (UID) and a password (PWD).